# JPA/Hibernate: It's possible to associate List attribute to a jpql query?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I Have 3 tables:
Invoice (id, userReadeableNum, ...)
Order (id, userReadeableNum, ...)
InvoiceOrderRel (id, invoceId, orderId, insertDate, ...)

I want to create a List property on Invoice Class with userReadableNum of Order class.

Something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="INVOICE")
@Immutable
public class Invoice implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="INV_ID")
    private long invId;
    //many attributes

    /*I know that this annotation does not exists, i want to know if there's something similar*/
    @ByQuery("select o.userReadableNum from Order o join o.invoiceOrderList iol where iol.order.invId = :invId") 
    private List<String> orderNums;
    //etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never heard of something like that, but you could create a @ManyToMany relation to solve this problem. JPA and hibernate look at database tables as entities, so they expect PK and FKs.

With an @ManyToMany relationship, the `orderNums` property would need to be `List<Order>` as opposed to a list of strings. The `InvoiceOrderRel` would be your join table.

Here is a little information about [@ManyToMany](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/) mappings.

Comment: I thinking in performance here, but if there is no solution, probably i will use your suggestion.